# My pine script is influenced by the timeframe of my chart and I want to get ride of this

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

My Pine Script for Tradingview helps me to see when I should buy a Stock and when I should sell it.

Unfortunately it will only do this in a certain timeframe.

For example:

When I chose the time intervall of my Chart in Tradingview to "1 day", it will always just tell me to buy a Stock at one day and then recommends me to sell it on the same day, no matter what (even though I wrote at which price point it should recommend me to sell).

And when I choose another time intervall, for example "1 week", it will only recommend me to buy a stock and then sell it 7 days after the buy date. Even when it should recommend me to sell the stock much earlier or later when it reached a certain price.

What I want is that it buy and sell recommendations depend solely on the indicators and are not influenced by a timeframe I chose for the Chart in Tradingview.

I hope that my text is understandable and I would really appreciate if somebody could help me with this.

Thank you very much!

Here you can see my pine script:

```
//@version=5
strategy("MACD and EMA200 Strategy", overlay=true)

// EMA200
ema200 = ta.sma(close, 200)

// MACD
macdLine = ta.sma(close, 12) - ta.sma(close, 26)
macdSignal = ta.sma(macdLine, 9)

// MACD Level crosses MACD Signal Line up
macdCrossUp = ta.crossover(macdLine, macdSignal)

// MACD Level crosses MACD Signal Line down
macdCrossDown = ta.crossunder(macdLine, macdSignal)

// MACD is above 0
macdAboveZero = macdLine > 0

// MACD is below 0
macdBelowZero = macdLine < 0

// Long signal when the current price is above the EMA200 and the MACD is below zero and crosses up
longSignal = close > ema200 and macdCrossUp and macdBelowZero

// Short signal when the current price is below the EMA200 and the MACD is above zero and crosses up
shortSignal = close < ema200 and macdCrossDown and macdAboveZero

// Entry strategy
if (longSignal)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (shortSignal)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Exit strategy
strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long", stop = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.91, profit = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.14)
strategy.exit("Exit Short", "Short", stop = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.09, profit = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.86)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `profit` argument of the `strategy.exit()` expect the price in ticks. However, you are trying to pass a price value. In that case, you should use the `limit` argument instead of `profit`.

> ***profit (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Profit target (specified in ticks). If it is specified, a limit order is placed to
> exit market position when the specified amount of profit (in ticks) is
> reached. The default value is 'NaN'.
>
> ***limit (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Profit target (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a limit order is
> placed to exit market position at the specified price (or better).
> Priority of the parameter 'limit' is higher than priority of the
> parameter 'profit' ('limit' is used instead of 'profit', if its value
> is not 'NaN'). The default value is 'NaN'.